# Disable deep linking and hash tag changes in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, navigation

I have seen many techniques and advice for getting deep linking to work in jQuery Mobile, but my situation requires just the opposite.

I have a multi-page document, completely self-contained.  I want the entry point to the app to be the first page, and to disable any deep links (**edit**: by "deep links" I mean bookmarks , or simply the ability to return) to the other pages in the document.  I also do NOT want navigation within the app to affect the hash tag.  In other words, if the user is in my app, and they hit their browser's back button, I want them to go to whatever page they were looking at before they entered my app, even if they are not on my first page.

What I have tried is to set the changeHash option on the mobile.changePage method to "false" on all my internal backward and forward navigation.  But the result is that when they use their browser's back button, they go TWO pages back.  Furthermore, this technique has not disabled deep linking, as I wanted it to do.

I'm hoping that someone else can advise without the necessity of me providing code examples, since my code is otherwise rather complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `changeHash` completely on `mobileinit` event. Modifying global defaults should be placed in *head* after *jQuery.js* and before *jQuery Mobile*.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
   $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
  });
</script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

And then, you need to listen to *back* button on `navigate` event and take user through history, using `window.history.back()`.

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  if (data.state.direction == 'back') {
    window.history.back();
    return false;
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/QYFez/show/)**

Comment: But how do you disable deep links?  On your example, I can still get directly to Page 3 by simply adding the hash-tag #p3 at the end of your URL in my browser's address bar.  I don't want to allow this in my app.  I want all attempts to enter the app to be forced to start at the first page.

Comment: @Joel add `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` on `mobileinit`.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks, Omar. Now we're getting somewhere. I also disabled pushStateEnabled, although that might not have been necessary. I still have an issue with using the browser's back button: from anywhere within my app, if I use the back button, the browser will go back TWO pages, not to the page I was looking at before I entered my app, but to the page before that; and then, if I use the forward button, I go right into my app, always skipping the page in-between. I will next try the second part of your suggestion. If I had enough points to up-vote your solution, I would.

Comment: The window.history.back suggestion did not solve the second problem (the one about skipping back TWO pages).

Comment: @Joel, I thought `window.history.back()` solved it. I will dig deeper in history API. Regarding _forward_, also `data.state.direction` returns _forward_.

Comment: @Joel its weird that `window.history.back()` doesn't work well for you. on chrome it works well, i'll test it on iphone http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eAnn8/show/

Comment: Same strange behavior with your jsfiddle.  It goes from Home, to Page Two, to Page Three, to Page Four.  When I hit the browser's back button from Page Four, it takes me back to the page I was on before the one that contains messages that I'm reading and replying to right now.

Comment: @Joel its working well on desktop and iphone 5 safari, i dont know what's wrong with it. all modern browsers support history api.

Comment: It certainly is strange.  Safari is what I'm using everywhere here, too (desktop, iPad), all latest versions.  Oh, well.  I can move on and revisit the issue at some future time.