# Preventing Jquery Mobile from processing URL hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile in an existing web application. The problem is, Jquery Mobile is processing all URL hashes. For example:

```
mysite.com/#foo
```

Here, the hash 'foo' is being sent to Jquery Mobile, and it is processing it, instead of letting my non-jquery mobile code process it.

Is it possible to prevent Jquery Mobile from interfering with the url hash?

Comment: Have you tried `data-ajax="false"` on the link?

Comment: @mhartington I want the url to be bookmarkable, so if someone types in `mysite.com/#foo`, I want that to work without going to JqueryMobile as well.

Comment: Because JQM uses ajax and hijacks URL. Mobile.com/#foo won't work without passing through index page first.

Comment: @Omar That's fine. Everything will work, if only Jquery Mobile doesn't do anything and just let my code handle the hash.

Comment: In this case, disable `hashListeningEnabled` on `mobileinit`. Also, you may want to disable `changeHash`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033874/disable-deep-linking-and-hash-tag-changes-in-jquery-mobile/21040021#21040021

Comment: @Omar Thanks! Please post as answer, and I'll accept. And, i'll give you a bounty too.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tested it and made sure it works for your purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of jQuery Mobile is listening to [`hashchange`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/hashchange/) event and updates *URL hash* in order to handle *history* of pages, only when *Ajax* is enabled.

To handle pages linking, both `changeHash` and `hashListeningEnabled` properties should be disabled on first run [`mobileinit`](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/). This event fires before loading jQuery Mobile library and `.ready()`; it should be used to change [*Global Settings*](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/) of the framework.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.extend( $.mobile, { 
      changePage.defaults.changeHash: false,
      hashListeningEnabled: false
    });
 });
</script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: In my code, for whatever reason, the `mobileinit` callback was not being called, possibly because jquery mobile was already initialized before my code was called. So, in my code, I just do `$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;` and `$wnd.$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;` in my own initialize method, and it works.

Comment: this is my method for doing this in google web toolkit: 

`private native void disableJqMobile()
    /*-{
           $entry(function()
           {
               $wnd.$.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
               $wnd.$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
           }) ();
       }-*/;`

Comment: @click thanks for the heads up, it'll definitely help others.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `encode/decodeURIComponent` to "hide" your hashes from JQM?

I'm not using it directly for hashes, but I need me own logic for processing links like this:

```
   ./foo/index.html#document/subfolder/items?sort=descending
```

which JQM will does not allow currently because slashes and query params after a hash are ignored (params) or added to the folder path (`/foo/subfolder/items/`).

However doing this:

```
   ./foo/index.html#document%2Fsubfolder%2Fitems%3Fsort%3Ddescending
```

goes unnoticed by JQM.

Should also work for the hash.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `data-url` for this.

[See this article](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=196#.U6Cp0CGD5UM)

```
<a data-identity='cat5' data-url='?cat=5' href='javascript:void(0);' >listitem text</a>
```

A bit old but still should work

Comment: That's not enough, I need the urls to be bookmarkable. E.g if someone goes to `mysite.com/#foo`, I want Jquery Mobile to not try to process that either.